# Matplotlib will not import even though it is installed. Using visual studio code

Tags: python, visual-studio, matplotlib

[Here is a picture of my terminal.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAzsk.png)

I cannot figure out what is going on, I've spent hours trying to make this import work. Please help

Comment: Hey! Welcome to Stackoverflow. If you don't mind me asking where exactly are u using `style` it seems that it might be the source of your error.

Comment: Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Comment: Python installation where you added the library != Python installation used to run the program.

Comment: I appreciate your time and effort in my post. Thank you for editing and answering. However, I am going to have to give the prize to the guy who specifically stated where to change the environment for Python. Also, this is literally my second day using this and using Python. You are going to have to forgive me for mindlessly throwing a screenshot in because I was frustrated with searching google for hours.

Comment: Rohan Nagavardhan, I have no idea what that even is, but I think it is now fixed. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from the obvious of uninstalling and reinstalling matplotlib, I would recommend clicking the bottom left corner of VSCode and make sure it is pointed at your virtual environment. Even though in your terminal you are in a venv, it looks as if VSCode may not be.

Comment: You sir, you are a genius. IQ of at least 300. That seems to work, thank you very much :)!